# one sql instead of 2 for counting

Tags: sql, oracle

I have read a thread on this but when I tried it I can`t manage to make it work.
I want to count all the male and females from a table like so:

```
Select 
count(case when substr(id,1, 1) in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) as M, 
count(case when substr(id,1, 1) in (3,4) then 1 else 0 end) as F 
from users where activated=1
```

The ideea is that a user having an id starting with 1 or 2 is male
My table has 3 male entries and 2 are activated and it returns (*the case statement doesn`t work*)

```
M,F
2,2
```

Any input would be appreciated

```
id    activated
123   1
234   0
154   1
```

Comment: could you show some id samples, telling which are males and which females ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SUM` instead. `COUNT` will count all non null values.

```
Select 
SUM(case when substr(id,1, 1) in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) as M, 
SUM(case when substr(id,1, 1) in (3,4) then 1 else 0 end) as F 
from users where activated=1
```

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT` will give you the number of non-null values, whatever they are. Try `SUM` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your Oracle version is 10g or later, as an alternative, you can use `regexp_count` function. I assume that the `ID` column is of `number` data type, so in the example it explicitly converted to `varchar2` data type using `TO_CHAR` function. If the data type of the `ID` column is `varchar2` or `char` then there is no need of any type of data type conversion.

Here is an example:

```
SQL> create table M_F(id, activated) as(
  2    select 123,   1 from dual union all
  3    select 234,   0 from dual union all
  4    select 434,   1 from dual union all
  5    select 154,   1 from dual
  6  );

Table created

SQL> select sum(regexp_count(to_char(id), '^[12]')) as M
  2      ,  sum(regexp_count(to_char(id), '^[34]')) as F
  3    from M_F
  4   where activated = 1
  5  ;

         M          F
---------- ----------
         2          1
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4668e/1)

Comment: Thank you for you`r input on this matter, I choose xdazz's answer (too bad one can`t choose multiple )because I am a man of my word, also I didn`t knew the regexp_count() function, verry nice :)